# Create plain object from URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter / cleaner way of creating a plain object from [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) than this:

```
const uri = new URL('https://tempuri.org/?token=secret&test=true')
const result = {}
for (let p of uri.searchParams) {
  result[p[0]] = p[1]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{ token: 'secret', test: 'true' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/forEach) method of `URLSearchParams`. Or convert it to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (the spread operator would also work `[...uri.searchParams]` if you prefer that syntax) and use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const uri = new URL('https://tempuri.org/?token=secret&test=true');

const result1 = {};
uri.searchParams.forEach((value, key) => (result1[key] = value));
console.log("result1", result1);

const result2 = Array.from(uri.searchParams)
  .reduce((object, [key, value]) => (object[key] = value, object), {});
console.log("result2", result2);
```

Comment: Of course you can also use smaller variable names to reduce the size if you like. `.reduce((o, [k, v]) => (o[k] = v, o), {})` I left them larger making the code better understandable (but taking up more space).

Answer (score 4):

Since ES6 there is a cleaner solution with [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const url = 'https://tempuri.org/?token=secret&test=true';
const params = new URL(url).searchParams;
Object.fromEntries(params);
```

It will output an object like this:

```js
{ token: 'secret', test: 'true' }
```

See browser compatibility of [Object.fromEntries on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#browser_compatibility). Basically all browsers and Node.js 12+ except Samsung Internet, Opera Android, and Internet Explorer. Time to say goodbye to the old browsers :)